# Do I need to add specific information to send mail through python?

Tags: python, sendmail

I am using the following code below:

```
import smtplib
import zipfile
import tempfile
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

#...

def send_file_zipped(the_file, recipients, sender='email@email.com'):
    myzip = open('file.zip', 'rb')


    # Create the message
    themsg = MIMEMultipart()
    themsg['Subject'] = 'File %s' % the_file
    themsg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    themsg['From'] = sender
    themsg.preamble = 'I am not using a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'
    msg = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
    msg.set_payload(myzip.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(msg)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=the_file + '.zip')
    themsg.attach(msg)
    themsg = themsg.as_string()

    # send the message
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", "587")
    smtp.connect()
    smtp.sendmail(sender, recipients, themsg)
    smtp.close()

#running this
send_file_zipped('file.zip', 'email@email.edu')
```

I have tried different variations to try and make it connect successfully here, but I am at a loss here. The error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Zeroe/Documents/python_hw/cgi-bin/zip_it.py", line 99, in <module>
send_file_zipped('file.zip', 'email@email.com')
File "/Users/Zeroe/Documents/python_hw/cgi-bin/zip_it.py", line 40, in send_file_zipped
smtp.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/smtplib.py", line 319, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/smtplib.py", line 294, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 404, in create_connection
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 395, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I am going to assume that my issue lies in connecting with the smtp server, but I don't know what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smtp.connect()` is wrong/redundant. The [`smtplib.SMTP(...)`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP) calls `.connect` upon initialization. A bare [`.connect`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.connect) call without any parameters means connection to `localhost` and if you do not have a SMTP server running on your machine you'll get an error.

However your goal is to send mail through GMail. Note that GMail's SMTP [requires authentication](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287), which you are not doing.

Your last lines should be accordingly:

```
# send the message
smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",  587)
smtp.helo()
smtp.starttls()                 # Encrypted connection
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login(username, password)  # Give your credentials
smtp.sendmail(sender, recipients, themsg)
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Wow, finally someone can explain it!!! I really appreciate. Even though it failed, its the first sign of something finally happening lol. The error I am getting is "smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server" Should I use smtp_ssl() ?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. My Mac does not have support for STARTTLS but I took away the starttls function as well as ehlo and helo as the python documentation said its not necessary if you don't use TTLS. I used SMTP_SSL instead and just added my hostname and it was successful! I really appreciate the time you took out to give me an actual explanation as most people just direct me to the links that give me the error to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem, but you're specifying the port number as a string, and that's probably not going to work.

Comment: Yup, tried both SMTP() and SMTP_SSL() with non string host and still the same issue. Question though, how do I figure out my computers default hostname? I looked it up, and people say just type hostname in the command line, but nothing echoes on the screen, so not sure